# Can I use mgconsole from Memgraph Platform to connenct to remote Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

Can I somehow use `mgconsole` that is part of Memgraph Platform to connect to some other non-docker based Memgraph instance? I know that I can run it with `docker run -ti --entrypoint=mgconsole memgraph/memgraph-platform` but that is for my Memgraph Platform.